# Python-Twilio Installation issue on mac?

Tags: python, macos, twilio

I am trying to learn Python through Udacity, and the topic is on Twilio for this chapter. I installed Twilio through the terminal as suggested:

```
Tonys-MacBook-Pro:Versions tonychu$ sudo easy_install twilio
Password:
Searching for twilio
Best match: twilio 6.3.dev0
Processing twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg
twilio 6.3.dev0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for twilio
Finished processing dependencies for twilio
```

the results suggest it is successfully installed, however when I tried to import twilio throught IDLE, it is suggested otherwise. Anyway i can resolve this? Thank you.

```
Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.

>>> import twilio
>>> print(twilio.__version__)
6.3.dev0
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tonychu/Documents/Programming/Python/send_text.py", line 1, in     <module>
    from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
  File "/Users/tonychu/Documents/Programming/Python/twilio.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(twilio.__version__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I suggest installing Twilio using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) as follows:

```
pip install twilio
```

If you don't have pip installed you can run the following on terminal:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

After installing Twilio you will then have the latest version of the stable [Twilio library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install) which as of time of writing is 5.4.0. But you can always check the latest version [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twilio).

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Hello Thanks for replying. I have ran `sudo easy_install pip` and `sudo pip install twilio`, but i am still facing the same problem running the program. Would it be possible to contact you through email or skype?

Comment: Sure, drop me an email on marcos@twilio.com

Comment: I got this error on MacOS high sierra
-bash: wget: command not found

Comment: @alsadk have a look at this link on how to get wget on your Mac. https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-and-configure-wget-on-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

http://twilio-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html
tells us 
Check to make sure that you don’t have a file named twilio.py; Python will try to load the Twilio library from your twilio.py file instead of from the Twilio library.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your code not with twilio

use this

```
from twilio.rest import Client
```

Instead of

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
```